# how to hold a selected list value after clicking go button?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page where a dropdown list is populated from the mysql database and **when a user make a selection and click 'go' button, data regarding that selected item will display on page**. Now everything is working perfectly in my page but the list item names are automatically display as default.
For example: there are 4 list items,Featured art, pop art, nature art, fantasy art. **when user select pop art and press go button, the data related to this are displayed on page but the dropdown list does not hold pop art name as selected in list**. Even then dropdown list shows Featured art as default. There is no problem of fetching data, but I want to display **as selected pop art or nature art or fantasy art or featured art in dropdown list** (*not only the featured art*)and its related data on page and so on. I think my point is clear to all. Help me please.

Here is code:

```
<select name="category">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, art_name FROM category;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
<option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['art_name']; ?></option>

<?php

 }
 ?>
 </select>
 <input name="go" type="submit" value="Go" /></div>


 <div align="center" class="showimage">
 <ul class="display">

 <?php
  $id = (int)$_POST['category'];
 $sql_search = "SELECT id, categoryid, path FROM list WHERE categoryid = $id";
 $search = mysql_query($sql_search);
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT autodisplay FROM list WHERE categoryid = 2");
 if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
 ?>


<li><a href="<?= $row['path']; ?>" class="highslide" onClick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="<?= $row['path']; ?>" border="0"></a></li>
<?php }

 }

 else {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
 ?> 
 <li><a href="<?= $row['autodisplay']; ?>" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="<?= $row['autodisplay']; ?>" border="0"></a></li>
  <?php 
   }
   }
  ?>
 </ul>
```

[This is the running page](http://monomita.arbionics.com/Becuart/Site/DOCS/main.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make <option selected="selected"> set by MySql and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969762/how-to-make-option-selected-selected-set-by-mysql-and-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your select list with the following:

```
<select name="category">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, art_name FROM category;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>

        <option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"<?=($_POST['category']==$row['id'] ? ' selected="selected" : '')?>><?= $row['art_name']; ?></option>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I've added an if statement to check if the row id matches the posted variable - if so set the option value to selected.