# Set name to dropdownlist from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a problem with my dropdownlist. When i press something in the dropdown then it will fill my table which I don't show here. But what I want is that **the dropdown has to save the thing i pressed and give himself that name.** I don't really know how to do this.

Look at this [how to hold a selected list value after clicking go button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807620/how-to-hold-a-selected-list-value-after-clicking-go-button).

*My code:*

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for='Select'>head:</label>
                    <select  class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php
                            //My $con is someone where else.
                            $resultName = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ond");                             
                            while ($row = $resultName->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            echo '<option value="'.$row["ondID"].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>'; 
                                    }                               
                    ?>
                    </select>                               
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </form>
```

Comment: can you update your question as per your need @Xaml ?

Comment: e.g. - <option value="test">Test</option>, do you want "Test" ?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: "When i press somehting int the dropdown then it will fill my table which I don't show in here" , fill my table means ? do you want to insert it somewhere ? @Xaml

Comment: Kindly do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a name to the dropdownlist. This is what I understood based on the  above comments.

```
 <select class="form-control" name="anyname" onchange="this.form.submit()">
   <!--Rest of the code-->
 </select>
```

Comment: No i don't want to give a name like that. I want to give a name based on which element is clicked in the dropdownlist.

Comment: But see the top comment of the page.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment i understood that you want selected dropdown option value with `onchange()` event.

```js
function check(val)
{
 alert(val);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for='Select'>head:</label>
  <select  class="form-control" onchange="check(this.value)">
   <option value="test">Test</option>
   <option value="test1">Test1</option>
  </select>                               
 </div>  
</div>  
</form>
```

Comment: No i don't want to give a name like that. I want to give a name based on which element is clicked in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Yes, I did check it.

Comment: If I use it like this. Then it doesn't have a function in my tabel which I did not show in here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```js
<script>
function getDropdownVal(val){
 alert(val);
}

</script>
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for='Select'>head:</label>
                    <select  class="form-control" onchange="getDropdownVal(this.value)">
                    <?php
                            //My $con is someone where else.
                            $resultName = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ond");                             
                            while ($row = $resultName->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            echo '<option value="'.$row["ondID"].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>'; 
                                    }                               
                    ?>
                    </select>                               
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for='Select'>head:</label>

                <select class="form-control" id="search" type="select" value="<?php echo $form-control ?>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option selected="selected"><?php echo "{$_POST['search']} "; ?></option>
                  <option>Example 1</option>
                  <option>Example 2</option>
                  <option>Example 3</option>
                <?php
                        //My $con is someone where else.
                        $resultName = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `table` where `Name`");                             
                        while ($row = $resultName->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row["ondID"].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>'; 
                                }                               
                ?>
                </select>                               
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807620/how-to-hold-a-selected-list-value-after-clicking-go-button please look at this. It is like this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
<?php $selectedValue = isset($_POST['selectName']) ? $_POST['selectName']: ""; ?>
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for='Select'>head:</label>
        <select name="selectName" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="">SELECT</option>
            <option <?php if ($selectedValue=='test') echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="test">Test</option>
            <option <?php if ($selectedValue=='test1') echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="test1">Test1</option>
        </select>                               
    </div>  
</div>  
</form>
<?php if($selectedValue) echo "You have select <strong>" . $selectedValue . "</strong>"; ?>
```

In your code :

```
$resultName = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ond");
$output="";
while($row = $resultName->fetch_assoc())
{
    $output .= '<option ';
    if($selectedValue == $row["ondID"])
    {
        $output .= "selected='selected'";
    }
    $output .= ' value="' . $row["ondID"] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</option>';
}
```